# Where can I find spark.hadoop.yarn.* properties?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, databricks

I was trying to run spark(1.6.0) application which was using `com.databricks.spark.csv` jar to load csv file on yarn client mode from eclipse. It was throwing
    `CSVRelatio$annonfunc$func not found` exception. That was resolved by setting

```
spark.hadoop.yarn.application.classpath
```

property in `SparkConf`.

My question is `spark.hadoop.yarn.application.classpath`property was not 
     listed in any of the spark official documents. So where can I find all such 
     properties? I know it is silly questions but there are many beginners who 
     refer official 
     documents (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/configuration.html) and they 
     are not at all aware about these properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not listed because there are not Spark properties. `spark.` prefix is used only, so Spark recognizes, that these should be parsed, and put into `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration`.

Where to look for a documentation? You should check Hadoop documentation for a corresponding component. For example for YARN: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

You should also not that Spark has its own classpath related properties including:

- `spark.jars`
- `spark.packages`
- `spark.driver.extraClassPath` / `spark.executor.extraClassPath`
- ....

Comment: Yes I checked yarn-defaut.xml which has yarn.application.classpath. But I was not able to figure it out that why spark.hadoop.yarn not spark.yarn.application.classpath ?  It worked by setting spark.jars property which adds listed jar files to driver and executor's classpaths.

Comment: AFAIK `spark.yarn` would be a Spark property (Spark property used with YARN as cluster manager). `spark.hadoop....` is a Hadoop property.